# How to write a script on bash named guess_number and RANDOM if statement?

Tags: linux, bash

Need help writing the script is it like this want the number to be guessed between 0 to 10 .

```
num=$(($RANDO%11) 

read -p "Enter an integer between 0 and 10" input

if [$RANDOM%=4]; then

echo "correct" 

else

echo "you got it wrong guess again

fi

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

For doing that you can try this method:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter an integer between 0 and 10:  " input
if [ "$input" -ge "0" ] && [ "$input" -le "10" ]; then
     echo "correct"
else 
    echo "wrong"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

rand=$(( ( RANDOM % 10 )  + 1 ))

while : ; do
     read -p "Enter an integer between 0 and 10 :  " input
    [ "$input" -eq "$rand" ] && echo -e "\nCorrect\n" && break
    echo -e "\n  Try again...\n"
done
```

**output:**

```
$ bash rand.sh

Enter an integer between 0 and 10 :  8

  Try again...

Enter an integer between 0 and 10 :  9

  Try again...

Enter an integer between 0 and 10 :  1

  Try again...

Enter an integer between 0 and 10 :  2

  Try again...

Enter an integer between 0 and 10 :  3

  Try again...

Enter an integer between 0 and 10 :  4

Correct
```